# ARIA announce that data has been added or removed from a table?

Tags: html, angular, accessibility, wai-aria

I am working on an Angular app where a user clicks a button which causes data to be added to or removed from the data source of a table elsewhere on the page.

When the user clicks the button, data is fetched and added to the table's data source.  So it now has a new row.

I am trying to make this accessible to screen readers, for example they might speak "row added" and speak the row's contents.

Can this even be accomplished?

Comment: Yes but there are a few items we need to know. Is this new data a single row or multiple rows? Where is the button relative to the table? Does the button make it clear that new data will be added to the table? Any chance of a minimal fiddle so there is something to demo with as that would make it easier. However the answer will either be `aria-live` or focus management if you want to have a quick look into those.

Comment: the user makes a bunch of selections in (an accessible) form, then click an "add item" button.  Think a shopping list. the Table is below the form, and once the user fills the table as desired with rows/items they would click "check out"

Comment: Then i would probably say you either need to do nothing (as it is expected that an item will get added to that list and they can always enter the table and jump to the last row if it is properly marked up and you have good headings and the instructions make it clear what happens on submitting the form etc.) or use `aria-live` to say "item added to list". I don't think you need anything complicated here. But yet again, hard to judge without seeing it.

Comment: I agree with @GrahamRitchie with a possible minor tweak.  If there's any kind of a toast message that says "row has been added", then that would have to be announced via `aria-live` (WCAG 4.1.3).  However, I suspect the sighted user just sees the row added and no message is displayed.  But I wanted to point out that possibility.

Comment: Thanks.  I wound up creating an alert that is only exposed to screen readers that appears when the button is clicked (as part of the function that was called by the button).  It toggles an `*ngIf` on the alert to true for 2 seconds.